# Compilation error not found: value x but I declared it already, what's wrong

Tags: scala

```
    result.map { res =>
      val totaldocs: Int = res.value
      // do something with this number
    }
    //val  totaldocs = 60
    val totalpages:Int = (totaldocs/ipp)+1
```

Compilation error not found: value x but I declared it already, what is wrong with my implementation, sorry I am new to play framework and  scala programming language.

[image]

Comment: can you provide the full compiler output? with lines

Comment: There is no `x` mentioned in this code. It'll give a different error. When asking about compilation errors, always make sure you are using the same version of code which gives you the error, and provide the complete message.

Comment: I updated my question

Comment: You really need to read some Scala tutorial/books

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say this line is the problem:

`val totalpages:Int = (totaldocs/ipp)+1`

because `totaldocs` is only defined inside the `map` scope

maybe you want something like:

```
private def getTotalPages(query:BSONDocument, ipp:Int) (implicit ec: ExecutionContext) = {
    val key = collectionName + ":" + BSONDocument.pretty(query)
    Logger.debug("Query key = "+key)
    val command = Count(query)
    val result: Future[CountResult] = collection.runCommand(command)
    result.map { res =>
      val totaldocs: Int = res.value
      // do something with this number

      val totalpages:Int = (totaldocs/ipp)+1
      Logger.debug(s"Total docs $totaldocs, Total pages $totalpages, Items per page, $ipp")
      totalpages
    }
  }
```

but now it will return a Future[Int] and you will have to deal with the future on the caller.

> Note: this is just one solution, depending on your code it may not be the most adequate one

Comment: recursive value totalDocs needs type

Comment: what you mean :you will have to deal with the future on the caller.?

Comment: Meaning that this method signature will change, and the method that calls this one will probably have to change some code